# fadeIn Animation not working in IE (all versions)

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

fadeIn animation is not working in IE for following coding. Basically this is a dropdown menu and when I hover the cursor on a parent menu can see the animation in Chrome, Mozilla and Opera but the problem seems on IE only.

Thank you in advance.

```
    function mainmenu(){
$(" #nav ul ").css({display: "none"}); // Opera Fix
$(" #nav li").hover(function(){
        $(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility: "visible",display: "none"}).fadeIn(400);
        },function(){
        $(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility: "hidden"});
        });
}



 $(document).ready(function(){                  
    mainmenu();
});
```

Comment: What javascript framework are you using?

Comment: one has to assume jQuery, but it would be good to confirm that (I've added it as a tag to the question since it looks like jquery code, but if not, please amend to whatever it is)

Comment: It would help to see the HTML as well, and a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) would be a plus.

Answer (score 0):

IE8 and earlier have extremely poor support for fading effects.

IE9 is a lot better, but if you're dealing with IE8 and earlier you'll always have to accept that the browser will limit what you can do.

jQuery does an amazing job of hiding the complexities of this from the developer: all you need to know about is the `.fadeIn()` method, for any browser. But behind the scenes, IE6/7/8 will always be working differently.

You haven't shown us the HTML code related to the issue, but one of the big problems that IE8 has with fading is with images. If the HTML being faded includes images, you are very likely to encounter problems with fading in IE8 and earlier.

There are ways of working around it, but they're complicated. Basically, you'd need to fade each part of the code independently.

Hope that helps.